# how can I retrieve an integer value from an NSMutableArray on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

How would I get an integer value out of an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to use [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1234]];

//..

int theNumber = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```

Comment: To avoid warnings use this,
`NSInteger theNumber = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];` 
or
`int theNumber = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];`

Answer (score 0):

You have this extends if you want

Create file **extends.h** add this code and **#import "extends.h"** in your project :

```
/*______________________________ Extends NSMutableArray ______________________________*/
/**
 * Extend NSMutableArray
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@interface NSMutableArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index;
@end
/**
 * Extend NSMutableArray Method
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@implementation NSMutableArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index {
    NSInteger anIndex = index;
    NSObject *object = [self objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OK found ");
        return object;
    }

}
@end
/*______________________________ Extends NSArray ______________________________*/
/**
 * Extend NSArray
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@interface NSArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index;
@end
/**
 * Extend NSArray Method
 * By DaRkD0G
 */
@implementation NSArray (NSArrayAdd)
/**
 *  Get element at index
 *
 *  @param index
 */
- (NSObject *) getAt:(int) index {
    NSInteger anIndex = index;
    NSObject *object = [self objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    if (object == [NSNull null]) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OK found ");
        return object;
    }

}
@end
```

**USE :**

```
NSObject object = [self.arrayItem getAt:0];
NSObject object2 = [self.arrayItem getAt:50];
```